# IN6_SET_ADDR_UNSPECIFIED was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, linux

I am currently porting Visual studio c++ code to Linux. I am using Ret Hat version. When I compile the code I get this error:

error: 'IN6_SET_ADDR_UNSPECIFIED' was not declared in this scope

Can you please let me know what is the linux equivalent for the same. If there is no equivalent function, how can I edit the same to work on both linux as well as windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of Googling finds this:

```
inline void IN6_SET_ADDR_UNSPECIFIED(struct in6_addr *a) 
{ 
   memset(a->s6_bytes,0,sizeof(struct in6_addr)); 
}
```

... you could probably use that.

Comment: Yes, a bit of googling would give me the same result, but as we know s6_bytes is not supported in linux i.e. s6_bytes is not defined in struct in6_addr.